# Joomla change administrator start page

Tags: joomla3.0

I wonder if there is a way to change the start page in Joomla administrator. I would like to show a componenent right when the user logs in instead of the control panel.

Edit: I guess really what i'm looking for is a redirect to say index.php&option=com_mycomponent right when i login, but i still want to be able to access the control panel etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla 3.X
You need to override the cpanel component in your admin template by adding the file (and folder tree):
`[tpl_xxx]/html/com_cpanel/cpanel/default.php`

where tpl_xxx is your admin template to display by default.

Then you can display anything you like related to your component.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
//Load pane behavior
jimport('joomla.html.pane');
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

define(MYPATH_ADMINISTRATOR,JPATH_SITE.DS.'administrator'.DS.'components'.DS.'com_xxx'.DS);
require_once (MYPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'models'.DS.'xxx.php');
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_xxx', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

//initialise variables
$document   = JFactory::getDocument();
$user       = JFactory::getUser();

//load model
$xxxModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'xxx', 'xxxModel' );
$extraData      = $xxxModel->getExtraData();

//build toolbar
JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_( 'COM_XXX_XXX' ), 'home' );
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Find index.php inside administrator template you are using.
Inside of it, find a line containing:

```
$cpanel   = ($option === 'com_cpanel');
```

After that just add:

```
if($cpanel){
    $app->redirect("index.php?option=com_xxx"); 
}
```

to redirect to any component view you like.
First line of code exists in isis template, on line 99. If not, just adapt if condition to

```
if($option === 'com_cpanel')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the administrator template index.php file in administrator/template_name/index.php. Note: to avoid any update problems, you better clone the template if you're looking for a deep customization.
Also note that you can add/delete/update/publish/unpublish modules to the administrator template in www.yoursite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&filter_client_id=1

Comment: I am looking in the file but I can not understand where to change. Is there a way to set the default component/view or something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I had the same requirement. I fixed it by using Apache's mod_rewrite, taking advantage of the fact that no query string is present after logging in.

Edit "path/to/administrator/.htaccess" and add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule index.php index.php?option=<your_start_component>
```